"Universality" of Carathéodory extension
Given an outer measure $\pi^*\colon 2^X\to[0, +\infty]$ on a set $X$, the Carathéodory extension guarantees that the restriction of $\pi^*$ to
$$
\mathscr M := \{E\subseteq X : \forall F\subseteq X, \pi^*(F) = \pi^*(F\cap E) + \pi^*(F\setminus E)\}
$$
yields a complete measure space.
Several things can be said if $\pi^*$ comes from a premeasure $\mu$ on a ring $\mathcal R$ on $X$, that is $\pi^* = \mu^*$ (defined as usual via infimum; a.k.a. "the maximal outer measure extending $\mu$"):

$\mathscr M$ is the largest $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ containing $\mathcal R$ to which the restriction of $\mu^*$ is measure (shown here in Ramiro's answer to About uniqueness in the Caratheodory's Theorem). This is in some sense a "universal property" describing $\mathscr M$.

In general, $\mathscr M$ can further be enlarged to a $\sigma$-algebra on which $\mu^*$ (actually, its restriction on $\mathscr M$) can be extended $\sigma$-additively (the same post by Ramiro gives a simple example). Of course, the induced outer measure of this measure would be distinct (in particular, smaller) than $\mu^*$.


This raises the following questions:

Property (1) shows that $\mathscr M$ is a maximal $\sigma$-algebra to which $\mu^*$'s restriction is a measure. Can we say that it's the largest? That is, can we drop the assumption "containing $\mathcal R$"?

Is there some similar version of a "universal property" for the general Carathéodory extension where $\pi^*$ doesn't necessarily come from a premeasure?


I look forward to any thoughts/refs. Many thanks!

(Not directly related to the post title, but the second question above, in turn, raises another question: Are there outer measures that are not induced by any premeasure?)
